# Inner product space inequality with vectors on the same norm

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\left ( H,\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle \right )$ be an inner product space. If   $\| x \| = \| y \| = \| z |$  prove that 
$$
 \big | \langle x , x \rangle \langle z , y \rangle - \langle x , y \rangle \langle z , x \rangle \big | ^ { 2 } \leq \left ( \langle x , x \rangle ^ { 2 } - | \langle y , x \rangle | ^ { 2 } \right ) \left ( \langle x , x \rangle ^ { 2 } - | \langle z , x \rangle | ^ { 2 }\right ).
$$

Searching online I found about this exercise (just put $\| x \|=1)$:

[Show that $\left|z\cdot y -(x\cdot y)(z\cdot x)\right|^{2}\leq \left(1-\left|x\cdot y\right|^{2}\right)\left(1-\left|z\cdot x\right|^{2}\right).$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2520381/show-that-leftz-cdot-y-x-cdot-yz-cdot-x-right2-leq-left1-leftx-c)

However, not even the particular case I' ve able to success. What I tried to do was to expand the left term and right term and see what I could simplyfy.

Anyone have any idea how to solve this? Thanks in advanced

Comment: Have you tried using difference of squares on the right hand side, and/or adding and subtracting an appropriate term in the lhs?

Comment: Im stuck since I'm not using the hypothesys i,e if $\| x \| = \| y \| = \| z |$ then is thhere something I can conclude for the inner product of the vectors $x,y,z$.